# ffmpeg: silence sepecific parts of an audio track

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I silence (mute) specific intervals in a multichannel audio file ?

Can it be done with fade-in / fade-out ?

I couldn't do it with "aevalsrc", and "volume" doesn't support time specification !